# Initialize Git Repository From Web Interface

Tags: node.js, git, web-applications, amazon-ec2

I'm in the process of building a web application that (without getting into the exact application of these technologies) will allow users to create repositories and share them with one another.

I am in the initial design phase, and wanted to know what the best way to go about executing terminal commands from the interface would be. Ideally, users would be able to click a button and I would initialize a new git repository for them.

Note: During the design process, I will be hosting the site on my Amazon EC2 Instance that has git installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, you need to run `git` from a Node.js application. "Running" `git` is actually *spawning the `git` process,* and [this is something you can do natively.](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process)

```
// Spawn a git process.
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const git = spawn('git', ['init']);

// Hook into the close event. See the manual for other events.
git.on('close', (code) => {

    // You can check the return code here to see if an error occured.
    console.log('git init finished with return code ' + code);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response man. I'm gonna look into this in a bit, and if I run into anything later in the process I will surely reach out to you!

Comment: But of course! Remember to accept the answer if you found it the most helpful. :)